# Can i use static variable in spring service layer?

Tags: java, spring, static

I want to use static counter throughout application from service layer.

It is possible to use static counter in service layer of spring?

Answer (score 4):

By default, a spring bean is a singleton. So you shouldn't have to make a field static to make sure you only have one instance of it (although you can, of course: Java code is Java code).

What will matter, though, is that multiple thread will have access to your counter. So you'll have to make sure to make all these accesses thread-safe. The easiest way is probably to use an AtomicInteger or AtomicLong to implement the counter.

Comment: Agreed that a non-static AtomicInteger or AtomicLong is appropriate in this case.  A comment on "you shouldn't have to make a field static to make sure you only have one instance of it":  with instance variables, you could actually have two instances created for a singleton bean if you're using subclass based proxying (CGLIB).  For a simple counter, this shouldn't be an issue.  For an expensive resource created within the constructor of a singleton, this could be a consideration.